# Identifying variable in an ion thruster problem

Tags: kinematics, momentum, velocity, coulombs-law, ions

recently came across a school revision problem introduced my teacher about ion thrusters. With the assumption that we are ionising air (**Nitrogen**) and that the ions accelerate by mutual repulsion without any interference. The magnitude of the momentum transferred to the device is equal to the ion's momentum, which was derived from the possible kinetic energy which was specified to be *T* at 10 KeV. Then, my teacher gave us this equation for its velocity:

$$v^2 = \frac{2T}{m}=\frac{2 \,\times\,1\times 10^4 eV}{28 \,\times\,931\times10^6 MeV/c^2}= 7.7\times 10^{-7}^2$$

Does anyone know what the value $931\times10^6 MeV/c^2$ is?

Answer (score 0):

931 MeV = $931 \times 10^6$ eV, is the mass of the proton in energy units. Also 28 nucleons in Nitrogen. I don't think you need both the "M" ($=10^6$) in MeV and the explicit factor of  $10^6$.